# how to feed stock market data into python

Tags: python, pandas, stock

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/remote_data.html

I was looking at how i would go about feeding stock market data into python by means of pandas.

The examples shown on the website of the address above make sense, except it doesn't explain how to select a stock you want to look at the price/historical prices of.

In the very first example, there is a line of code as follows:

`f = web.DataReader("F", 'yahoo', start, end)`

So i thought maybe 'yahoo' is how they select a ticker.

But then when i referred to the price of yahoo on '2010-01-04', the values were different from what they have as follows:

```
Open               10.170000
High               10.280000
Low                10.050000
Close              10.280000
Volume       60855800.000000
Adj Close           9.151094
```

which left me utterly confused.

Comment: yahoo is the price source, and F (Ford) is the ticker.  From the docstring: Signature: DataReader(name, data_source=None, start=None, end=None, retry_count=3, pause=0.001)
...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple example of getting/plotting stock data (Google and Apple here):

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime
start = datetime.datetime.strptime('1/1/2015', '%m/%d/%Y')
end = datetime.datetime.strptime('2/20/2016', '%m/%d/%Y')
f = web.DataReader(['GOOG','AAPL'], 'yahoo', start, end)
print 'Adjusted Closing Prices'
print f['Adj Close'].describe()
ax = f['Adj Close'].plot(grid=True, fontsize=10, rot=45.)
ax.set_ylabel('Adjusted Closing Price ($)')
plt.legend(loc='upper center', ncol=2, bbox_to_anchor=(0.5,1.1), shadow=True, fancybox=True, prop={'size':10})
plt.show()
```

Comment: i get the following error message  No module named pandas_datareader.data

Comment: i use anaconda 2.3.0

Comment: Try `import pandas.io.data as web`.  You will get a warning that it will be removed in a future version in favor of pandas_datareader.

Comment: if i update my anaconda, will i have to use import pandas_datareader.data as web ?

Comment: i don't think it comes with the standard package.  I installed it with "pip install pandas-datareader".

Comment: @screenpaver need to import plt : 'import matplotlib.pyplot as plt'

Answer (score 0):

I think the "F" is the symbol of the stock which is for the Ford Motor Company, and the "Yahoo" is the data source which means the stock quotes of 
"F" is from Yahoo Financial.